# Bootstrap typeahed with popover adding extra typehead input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get Typeahead inside Popover, somehow i achieved it, but am showing typeahead with popover when i click a link, but each click on additional textbox with some additional elements also adding inside the popover. so popover is extending itself

Popover with typeahead

```
    var popOverSettings = {
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    selector: '#change-customer',
    title: '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>',
    content: function () {
        return $('#customer-popover').html();
    }
}

$('body').popover(popOverSettings).on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
         enableTypeAhead();
    });

  var numbers, countries, repos, arabic, nba, nhl, films, anExcitedSource;

  numbers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: [
      { num: 'one' },
      { num: 'two' },
      { num: 'three' },
      { num: 'four' },
      { num: 'five' },
      { num: 'six' },
      { num: 'seven' },
      { num: 'eight' },
      { num: 'nine' },
      { num: 'ten' }
    ]
  });

  numbers.initialize();

    function enableTypeAhead(){
      $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        displayKey: 'num',
        source: numbers.ttAdapter()
      });
    }
```

somewhere in internet i found that we can enable typeahead inside popver by adding

```
$('body').popover(popOverSettings).on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
        enableTypeAhead();
});
```

`on('shown.bs.popover'` doing the trick here, but am not sure why additional elements are adding inside popover

Example fiddle : [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6ydb2o79/2/)

Comment: you can try this little hack http://jsfiddle.net/6ydb2o79/6/, you are initiating the same typeahead each time you open the modal

Comment: Yes its working, but am looking for some better option

Comment: better option just initiate typeahead at dom ready